# Ember 1.4 Beta 6 hosed my Beta 5 app

Tags: ember.js

With the latest update - 2 hours ago, I'm unable to create a new application:

Just now, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined ember-data.js:68
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined app.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined models.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined router.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined views.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined controllers.js:1
```

I start my app as follows:

window.App = Ember.Application.create();

Was working fine with Beta 5 - before today.

calling scripts as follows:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js '></script>
<script src='http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember.js'></script>
<script src='http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js'></script>
```

can also see it in my previous question example:

http://jsbin.com/huvaq/2/edit

Which now results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined ember-data.js:68
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined runner:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'debug' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta channel was just updated 2 hours ago and it seems like something went wrong. In the mean time, you could just pick an earlier snapshot from http://builds.emberjs.com/